# Making two sites appear as single domain

Tags: apache, seo, reverse-proxy

I have two websites set up as follows

www.site1.com - IIS 6.0, Url rewriting with Helicon ISAPI Rewrite 2

www.site2.com - Apache

I've managed to make requests to www.site1.com/site2/ reverse proxy to www.site2.com/, so site2 appears to be part of site1. This was achieved by a RewriteProxy rule in the Helicon httpd.ini

However, to preserve SEO, I also need requests for www.site2.com itself to 301-redirect to www.site1.com/site2 - *except* of course when the request comes via the above reverse proxy. I believe this is possible via a conditional rewrite rule in the .htaccess file of site2, the condition being that if something unique about a request from site1 is detected, it serves the content, otherwise it 301 redirects.

The condition I'd wanted to use was the www.site1.com IP address, but in our scenario it's likely to change, so I need to use something different to identify such a request.

How else could this be achieved? Is the 301/reverse proxy combination a typical solution to this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

A slightly odd set-up perhaps but I think doable.

Just off the top of my head, I think that you would need to check the referrer header as part of the rewrite rules in .htaccess. So you would check to see if the referrer is NOT site1 before hitting the rule to rewrite using a 301 header.

If you need further help on setting the rules, let me know and I'll see if I can give you a more specific example - I'm a bit pressed for time just now.